# Express gateway jwt return Unauthorized

Tags: node.js, jwt, express-gateway

I'm trying jwt on express-gateway. But from the configuration gateway.config.yml it is in accordance with the documentation. but, thats always return unautorized.
my gateway.config.yml:

```
http:
  port: 8080
apiEndpoints:
  crudAPI:
    host: localhost
    paths:
      - '/users/get-user-data'
      - '/users/delete-user-data'
      - '/users/add-user-data'
      - '/users/get-one-user-data/*'
      - '/users/update-user-data'
      - '/users/update-pass-user-data'
serviceEndpoints:
  crudService:
    url: 'http://localhost:3004'
policies:
  - proxy
  - log
  - jwt
pipelines:
  crud:
    apiEndpoints:
      - crudAPI
    policies:
      - log:
        - action:
            message: "header===> ${req.headers.authorization}"
      - jwt:
        - action:
            secretOrPublicKey: 'secretAuth'
            checkCredentialExistence: false
            # passThrough: true
      - proxy:
        - action:
            serviceEndpoint: crudService
```

if passThrough set to true its work correctly. 
something went wrong?

Comment: Hey,

what you've put here is not enough to provide any suggestion/advice.

You'd need to show at least how you're doing the request to the gateway as well as how you're generating the user and the app you're trying to authenticate against!

Comment: sorry, this is my request at postman when passThrough: false
[link_1](https://ibb.co/4TL49xy)
.
And this is my request at postman when passThrough: true
[link_2](https://ibb.co/0jwXptY)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works well in EG. There was only a mistake on the JWT that I made on the backend API. Thank you for taking the time to investigate this case. I am very grateful for working with EG.

My backend API when authenticating JWT:

```
// JSON WEB TOKEN STRATEGY
passport.use(new JwtStrategy({
    // jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromHeader('authorization'), // WRONG
    jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),  // CORRECT
    secretOrKey: config.JWT_SECRET
}, async (payload, done) => {
    try {
        // find user specified in token
        const user = await User.findById(payload.sub);

        // handle if user doesnt exist
        if(!user) {
            return done(null, false);
        }

        // return the user
        done(null, user);
    } catch (error) {
        done(error, false);
    }
}));
```

Comment: Fantastic — glad to see you've been able to make it work.